# Присвоить много аргументов в конструкторе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Конструктор принимает много аргументов. Надо присвоить их одноименным переменным класса. Как это сделать более правильно/короче/красивше, чем перечислять подряд?

```
class X:
  def __init__(self, height, width, opacity, alpha, beta, gamma, theta):
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
    self.opacity = opacity
    # и т.д.
```

Comment: Перечислять подряд это и есть правильно/короче/красивше.

Comment: И что, никто до сих пор не предложил `class X(dict):`? И кстати, рекомендую не оставлять пустую инициализацию классов,  а наследоваться от `object`. Хотя может в Py3 это уже по умолчанию...

Comment: @МихаилМуругов с помощью рефлексии нельзя короче?

Comment: @0andriy зачем наследоваться от `dict` произвольному классу? метка 3 питона

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучшим способом является именно перечисление и явное присвоение каждого аргумента.

```
class X:
  def __init__(self, height, width, opacity, alpha, beta, gamma, theta):
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
    self.opacity = opacity
```

Так при работе в IDE в сможете быстро понять где именно появляется нужный вам параметр.

Comment: С помощью рефлексии нельзя короче?

Answer (score 3):

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        dict_ = {"height": 0}
        self.__dict__ = kwargs 
        for key, value in dict_.items():
            self.__dict__[key] = self.__dict__.get(key, value)
```

только место:

```
X(0, 1, 2)
```

надо писать:

```
X(height = 0, width = 1, opacity = 2)
```

Либо

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        dict_ = {параметр: значение по умолчанию}
        list_ = [параметры без значения по умолчанию]
        for key in list_:
            self.__dict__[key] = kwargs[key] 
        for key, value in dict_.items():
            self.__dict__[key] = self.kwargs.get(key, value)
```

Comment: Вид списка аргументов изменять нельзя. Как я узнаю, что нужное количество передано? + там ещё дефолтные значения есть

Comment: @rdug поправил.

Answer (score 0):

В `python` есть две переменные: `args` и `kwargs`. В первом случае аргументы будут позиционными, а во втором - по умолчанию.

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    self.args = args


def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.height = kwargs.get('height', 0)
    # etc.
```

Comment: Ещё раз -- вид списка аргументов изменять нельзя. Как я узнаю, что нужное количество передано?